# Metadata External xml Path Issue

Tags: grails-2.0, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, grails-config

I would like to read the metadata from the external xml file in my saml configuration . Can anybody tell me whether it is possible or not . if yes then how?

currently i tried with this:-

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.saml.metadata.sp.file = 'file:c://temp/idp_local.xml'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my web project I put metadata in resources under src directory. Content gets deployed inside WEB-INF/classes in the final WAR.
In your spring security configuration file you can then use this code for example:

```xml
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                                <beans:constructor-arg value="/metadata/TestFederationMetadata.xml"/>
                            </beans:bean>
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata"/>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:property name="metadataTrustCheck" value="false"/>
            </beans:bean>
```